Wifi adapter not found error while connecting to network
I am using Ubuntu 22.0 on a Asus TUF F15 and I am facing issues connecting to my wifi for the past few days.
I am able to connect to my wifi when the laptop is booted up, however I suddenly loose connection after a while  and I am unable to reconnect. I have tried connecting it to different networks and the issue is the same across all networks. I have also noticed that my laptop starts having issues with the suspend mode at exactly this time. I am unable to put it into a deep sleep as soon as the wifi stops working.
The issue gets temporarily fixed by restarting the laptop however but soon reappears after the laptop has been running for a while. Restart fixes issues related to deep sleep also.
I have tried restarting the network manager with sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager to no avail.
I am seeing a no wifi adapter found message in the wifi tab under settings.  Kindly let me know if you would need any more information to help me with this issue.
